# Android:stop refresh Activity when page move onto portrait to landscape mood

Tags: android, landscape-portrait, android-screen

I want to stop activity refresh when I move on to portrait  mood to landscape mood and I also want load file layout-land when it move to  portrait to landscape mood without any refreshment the activity.

I use `<activity android:name=".Login"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">`

but,In this method when I move onto   portrait to landscape mood ,It does not load the file from layout-land folder. what should I do for this? please someone help me.

Comment: the answer is here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android

Comment: make sure that you have main.xml in layout-land folder too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call method setContentView(R.layout.main) in onConfigurationChanged()

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        ///in case you have some EditTexts , save their input before setting the new layout.
        emailForConfigChanges = emailTextBox.getText().toString().trim();
        passwordForConfigChanges = passwordTextBox.getText().toString().trim();

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Now set the values back to the EditTexts .
    }
```

You just have to add this method to your activity as it handles all the orientation changes if you have declared "orientation" in your manifest.

**EDIT :** And if EditTexts lose their values on rotation, get their values before calling setContentView() in onConfigurationChanged(). See the edit above.

Comment: when I rotate,It loads file from layout-land but it lose the values,I mean If I enter some values to text-field then it rotates, it lose the values.is there any solution?

Comment: See the edit.Just set the saved values in EditTexts after setContentView() is called.

Answer (score 1):

I handled this problem only by addding `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks.it works but page refresh when it rotates.is there anyway to stop that?